# calculate area of map and set zoom level dynamically

Tags: mapbox

Implemented mapbox with the below code to highlight specific group of regions-

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '{ACCESS_TOKEN}';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [-68.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
zoom: 4
});

map.on('load', function () {

map.addLayer({
'id': 'maine',
'type': 'fill',
'source': {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
'coordinates': [
                [
                    [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886],
                    [-66.96466, 44.8097],
                    [-68.03252, 44.3252],
                    [-69.06, 43.98],
                    [-70.11617, 43.68405],
                    [-70.64573401557249, 43.090083319667144],
                    [-70.75102474636725, 43.08003225358635],
                    [-70.79761105007827, 43.21973948828747],
                    [-70.98176001655037, 43.36789581966826],
                    [-70.94416541205806, 43.46633942318431],
                    [-71.08482, 45.3052400000002],
                    [-70.6600225491012, 45.46022288673396],
                    [-70.30495378282376, 45.914794623389355],
                    [-70.00014034695016, 46.69317088478567],
                    [-69.23708614772835, 47.44777598732787],
                    [-68.90478084987546, 47.184794623394396],
                    [-68.23430497910454, 47.35462921812177],
                    [-67.79035274928509, 47.066248887716995],
                    [-67.79141211614706, 45.702585354182816],
                    [-67.13734351262877, 45.137451890638886]
                ],
                [
                    [-73.9972808,40.750672],
                    [-73.986258,40.7157619],
                    [-73.9891809,40.7318292],
                    [-74.0182442,40.6886296],
                    [-74.0087681,40.7059736],
                    [-74.0129537,40.7096144],
                    [-74.0078064,40.7138637],
                    [-73.978636,40.726408],
                    [-73.9822316,40.7390449],
                    [-74.000594,40.7420017],
                    [-73.9980784,40.7255806],
                    [-74.0049277,40.720107]
                ]
            ]
}
}
},
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#223FFF',
'fill-opacity': 0.8
}
});
});
</script>
```

Example above, you will see two regions highlighted, one is MAINE and other is near New York.
Currently zoom level set is 4. I want to make it dynamic.

For the above example, what if, if we set of coordinates are from different region? One set of coordinates from USA while other set is from China or any other country.
It will highlight both of the regions with zoom level as 4 with center points set to say USA, but map page will not show the other region unless we minimize the zoom level manually on map.
I tried to find out the way to calculate highlighted regions on map, and based on this, setting up the zoom level. But, I didn't find anything related on their documentation.

If anybody has any idea on how to set zoom level dynamically based on regions highlighted, that would be greatly appreciated.

Reference -
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

Comment: Can you put your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this (in an angular application) by running a loop over the coordinates and calculating the minimum and maximum lat,lng values and setting the zoomLevel based on the difference.

```js
coordinates.map((element) => {
            lat_min = lat_min < element[0] ? lat_min : element[0];
            lat_max = lat_max > element[0] ? lat_max : element[0];
            lng_min = lng_min < element[1] ? lng_min : element[1];
            lng_max = lng_max > element[1] ? lng_max : element[1];
          });
zoomLevel = this.getZoomLevelForGeojsonArea(Math.abs(lat_min), Math.abs(lat_max), Math.abs(lng_min), Math.abs(lng_max));
```

Below is the calculation to determine the zoom level (the conditions can be modified as per requirement & the desired level of precision)

```js
getZoomLevelForGeojsonArea(lat_min, lat_max, lng_min, lng_max) {

    let dx = Math.abs(lat_max-lat_min);
    let dy = Math.abs(lng_max-lng_min);
    let d = dy > dx ? dy : dx;

    //return zoomlevel
    switch(true) {
      case d>100 : return defaultZoom ?? 0;
      case (d>75 && d<=100) : return 0.2;
      case (d>50 && d<=75) : return 0.4;
      case (d>40 && d<=50) : return 1.2;
      case (d>30 && d<=40) : return 1.4;
      case (d>20 && d<=30) : return 1.6;
      case (d>15 && d<=20) : return 1.7;
      case (d>10 && d<=15) : return 2.1;
      case (d>5 && d<=10) : return 2.7;
      case (d>2.5 && d<=5) : return 3.2;
      case (d>1 && d<=2.5) : return 3.8;
      case (d>0.5 && d<=1) : return 6;
      case (d>0.25 && d<=0.5) : return 7.2;
      case (d>0.125 && d<=0.25) : return 7.6;
      case (d>0.10 && d<=0.125) : return 8.2;
      case (d>0.01 && d<=0.10) : return 8.8;
      case (d>0.001 && d<=0.01) : return 9;
      default: return 9.6
    }

  }
```

Hope this helps..